# javascript object returning null

Tags: javascript

if i log the `snapshot.val` i see there id data.  but when i log `a` it displays null.

```
            var a = null;
            var b = null;
            firebase.database().ref('userInfo/' + senederId).on('value', snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot.val()); // returning data
                a = {
                    usersInfo: snapshot.val()
                }        
            });
            console.log(a); // its null in here
```

Comment: The call to firebase is asynchronous, the assigment `a = {....` does not happen before the `console.log(a);` line

Comment: Database operation is async.